# change the text field text using jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins

```
                <script>
        (function($) {
            $.fn.extend({

                animateMenu: function(options) {
                    var defaults = {
                        Color: '#ccc',
                    };
                    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
                    return this.each(function() {
                        var o = options;
                        var obj = $(this);


                        obj.mouseover(function() {
                            $(this).text("kasun");

                        }).mouseout(function() {
                            $(this).text("Wickramanayake");

                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#menu').animateMenu();
        });

    </script>
```

I created a small Jquery plugin to change the text on a text field when the mouse over and  mouse out
event is triggered.but it didnot work

Comment: its working see http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/MZh85/1/ have you include jquery file

Comment: It does not work for text field and cannot change the color